# Let injected services fall through multiple ViewModels

Tags: wpf, architecture, mvvm, service

I have a MainViewModel which gets injected some services automatically from MEFedMVVM.

This MainVM creates other ViewModels/Controllers. Those again create ObservableCollections and pass the constructor of the viewmodels put in the collection some services from above...

Is it good/bad/ok to let the services fall trough from ...

```
MainVM
--AdminVM
----Collection<1VM>
--PlannerVM
----Collection<2VM>
--etc...VM
```

to the other xVM`s ? or should I retrieve the service in code where I need it directly in the appropriate VM?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the services. If the services are "singletons", i.e. there can be only one service of `SomeService` then it doesn't make sense to let it cascade. Code that needs it can let MEF resolve the dependency automatically.

Otherwise, if there might be reason for multiple instances of a single service to exist, cascade makes sense.

Comment: well the services are singletons from MEFedMVVM. But I have ViewModels/Controllers and ViewModels wrapping a model which are created not by MEF but I need to pass services to them and this I do right now via cascading... I just thought a ViewMOdel should not create a service or know about it... it just gets injected...

Comment: @msfanboy: I don't quite understand what you describe, but we don't disagree: let MEF inject the services to ALL ViewModels. There's no need for `AdminVM` to get the service from `MainVM`.

Comment: but the MainVM creates the other VMs/Controller like AdminVM/PlannerVM/BillingVM etc... they need to be created manually, because they need data from each other, when I switch between them.

Comment: @msfanboy: Maybe it would be better to decouple the VMs from each other, then. In any case, you are asking if you should do X and now you are telling me that you can't. Why ask in the first place?

Comment: As I use MEFedMVVM at just 2 places I will kick it search for a proper DI container and create my MainViewModel from the app.xaml.cs